# Why javac accepts to compile classes with package declaration with incorrect tree structure

Tags: java, package, javac

I was wondering **why** the following steps are working.

Let's say that the actual file structure is:

```
 - src
  - Toto.java
```

the file `Toto.java` contains

```
package myPackage;
class Toto{}
```

The [official javac specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) states

> Arrange source files in a directory tree that reflects their package
>   tree. For example, if all of your source files are in \workspace, then
>   put the source code for com.mysoft.mypack.MyClass in /workspace in
>   \workspace\com\mysoft\mypack\MyClass.java.

I thought that

```
$ cd src
$ javac Toto.java
```

will output an error. **Instead, the compiler yields no error and compiles the proper file.**

Obviously,

```
cd src
javac PokerQ/Affichage.java
```

or

```
javac PokerQ/Affichage.java
```

don't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, you don't need to put your source files in a tree that matches the package hierarchy. The compiler will compile each class and store the package name internally. Regardless of how you organize the source directories, each generated `.class` file will know what package it corresponds to.

The potential problem is that, if you're compiling multiple classes, then some of those classes will refer to one another, most likely. The compiler, and the JRE, use directory hierarchy as a means of *finding* classes, when one class references another. By default, the compiler will place a compiled `.class` files in the same directory as its Java source. If the source directory is higgledy-piggledy, you end up with a set of `.class` files that are themselves not structured according to packages, which will make it hard to find them. You might still be able to get around the problem -- should you really want to -- by careful setting of the class search path in your `javac` or `java` command lines.

Moreover, if you specify a directory to the compiler using `-d <path>`, then it will construct a tree of compiled classes that matches the package hierarchy, however jumbled the sources are. I'm not sure that anybody uses the default approach, of having the compiled classes put into the same directories as sources and, in principle, you could probably construct a fairly complex, multi-package Java application where all the source files were in the same directory -- assuming you could keep track of them all.

Be that as it may, the idea that the source tree matches the package hierarchy is firmly entrenched in Java development methodology, whether it's always strictly necessary or not. IDE tools and build tools like Ant and Maven all assume this organization, so you'd have to be a bit bloody-minded to work any other way.